# Large blender 2.8 Project file won't open!

Tags: blend-files

As my title implies, my blender project won't open. I've been working with it for a while now, and now I can't open it. It's in blender 2.8 and I've tried 2.9, and my theory is that it has such a huge load of faces that my ram just curls up and dies. What happens is that my ram (16 gigs) gets fully hogged up, and blender tries to open it for a good 15 minutes, then just crashes to the desktop. I've tried to open it in every way possible, but no dice. If anyone can confirm my suspicions, or just help me in any way I would be WAAAAY grateful. It's a huge project and would hate to see it down the drain.

Comment: If you can open it with 2.8, then you don't  need 2.9. But if your project is taxing your computer so much, consider splitting it in smaller chunks, that are workable, else you will never be able to render it or do anything with it in the end.

Comment: Or get more ram...

Comment: yeah getting more ram is my current plan. how would you split it into chunks though if I can't even open my file?

Comment: You might need to create a new project and append parts of the larger project.